# Most Appropriate Use Of Async/Await When Not Returning The Task Directly?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I use async await a lot in my code, but it's occurred to me that I might not be doing it as appropriately as I should be.

I'm looking for confirmation of my understanding of the best way to handle async/await for methods which do multiple things and don't return the result of the task directly.

This is what I'd usually do when I just want to directly return the result of the task.

```
    //basic - 1 thing to do - directly return task
    public Task<string> ReturningATask(string key)
    {
        return _cache.GetStringAsync(key);
    }
```

However when I want to *do* something with the value of the task before returning, I've had the habit of just async'ing the method and awaiting the task within.

```
    //More than a single operation going on.
    //In this case I want to just return a bool indicating whether or not the key exists.
    public async Task<bool> ReturningABool(string key)
    {
        string foundValue = await _cache.GetStringAsync(key);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(foundValue))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

It occurs to me that ContinueWith is probably the more appropriate way to handle this.

Is the below example the generally the accepted way to handle this?
I got into my head "never use task.Result as it's blocking", but with ContinueWith, the task is already completed, so there's no blocking right?

```
    //The more correct way?        
    public Task<bool> ReturningATaskBool(string key)
    {
        return _cache.GetStringAsync(key)
            .ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Result))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            });
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: you *do* return task with async/await.

Comment: Yes sorry, you're quite right, I mis-spoke.  I think I messed up my 2nd code example, as what I'd usually do is just make it an async bool, rather than async Task<bool> which of course would not return a task.  Edited question to remove that bit.

Comment: You can do `return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time it doesn't make much of a difference. `async/await` has probably slightly more overhead than `ContinueWith` (though it really depends on the scenario), but I doubt that's something you should worry about. Just go for the one you find easier to read.

The only thing you should be careful about is that `await` will post the continuation to the current synchronization context, if any. This may be especially useful if you're in a winform/wpf application. On the other hand, `ContinueWith` executes the continuation on the current task scheduler (usually the threadpool).

> I got into my head "never use task.Result as it's blocking", but with ContinueWith, the task is already completed, so there's no blocking right?

That's correct, the way you use `ContinueWith` is fine.

Answer (score 4):

`ContinueWith` is a dangerous, low-level API. Specifically, it:

- Does not understand asynchronous continuations.
- Uses the *current* `TaskScheduler` (not the *default* `TaskScheduler`) as the default value for its `TaskScheduler` parameter.
- Does not have appropriate default behavior for continuation flags (e.g., `DenyChildAttach`).

`await` has none of these problems. You should use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`.

[See my blog for an exhaustive (exhausting?) discussion](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html).

Comment: hmmm, I was worried that there could be some "Gotchas" with ContinueWith, such as exception handling.
I'll stick with the await'ing that I'm used to.

Comment: @Steviebob ContinueWith existed before Async-Await was introduced and was used for Asynchronous implementation as a workaround, being non-blocking and much simpler than APM. Now post introduction of async-await, there's no better option.